# Apache Spark 1.2.1 standalone cluster giving java heap space error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I need information about, how to figure out how much heap space(memory) would be needed to operate on x mb(suppose x means 600 mb) in spark standalone cluster.

Scenario:

I have standalone cluster with 14gb memory and 8 cores. I want to operate(Reading data from files and writing it to  Cassandra) on 600 MB of data.

For this task I have SparkConfig as:

.set("spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec","800")

.set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.3")

And --executor-memory=5g --total-executor-cores 6  --driver-memory 6g at the time of submitting task.

In spite of above configuration,I getting java heap space error while writing data to Cassandra.

Below is the java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String fileName = args[0];

    Long now = new Date().getTime();

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true)
            .setAppName("JavaSparkSQL_" +now)
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.1.65")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9042")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160")
            .set("spark.cassandra.output.throughput_mb_per_sec","800")
            .set("spark.storage.memoryFraction", "0.3");

    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);


    JavaRDD<String> input =ctx.textFile    
("hdfs://abc.xyz.net:9000/figmd/resources/" + fileName, 12);
    JavaRDD<PlanOfCare> result = input.mapPartitions(new 
ParseJson()).filter(new PickInputData());

    System.out.print("Count --> "+result.count());
    System.out.println(StringUtils.join(result.collect(), ","));


 javaFunctions(result).writerBuilder("ks","pt_planofcarelarge",
 mapToRow(PlanOfCare.class)).saveToCassandra();

}
```

What configuration I am suppose to do?Am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and where do the error come?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Heap space error come while writing data to the Cassandra.

Comment: you need to share some code. maybe you are doing a collect over your rdd that results in a heap space error or maybe 1 of many others things you might be doing to blow up your heap! Your question is not solvable like this.

Comment: Right. I am doing collect as well.I will share code right now.

Comment: In order of magnitude, what is the size and count of your `JavaRDD result`?

Comment: I am giving 20 files,each of 32 MB as input and creating 12 slices of RDD.         The count of RDD is 340000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76461/discussion-between-eliasah-and-abhinandan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaRDD `collect` method return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.

So in your case, it will creates an array with 340000 elements which will result in a `Java Heap Error`, you may want to take a small sample of your data and `collect` it or you may want to save it directly to your disk.

For more information about JavaRDD, you can always refer to the [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDD.html).